# Unshadow global identifier in a class

Tags: c++, scope

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
class ident {};

class Base {
public:
  int ident;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  ::ident var; // refers to the global identifier
  ident var; // syntax error, refers to the base member
};
```

Is it possible to make it so `ident` refers to the global identifier in `Derived::method()`? Eventually completely hiding `Base::ident`? I cannot change `Base`, but I can make an intermediate class. I can add lines everywhere but the generation of the member variables will always refer to `ident` as `ident`.

It is a very unusual request, because it is for a templated code generator (SWIG).

Comment: Yes, add `int &ident = ::ident;` to `Derived`, or the intermediate class if you can't change the class definition of `Derived`.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but in my case the first one is a type, I edited my question

Comment: I do not understand. Now `ident` is *not* a 'global variable": it is a *type.* What exactly are you expecting `ident = 0` to do if it can be made to refer to the type?

Comment: Well, now the question changed shape so of course `ident = 0;` refers to the base member and not the _type_ `ident`. What would you like `ident = 0;` to do when `ident` is a _type_? Fail compilation I presume

Comment: The question you ask is still _"Is it possible to make it so `ident` refers to the global **variable** in `Derived::method()`?"_ though. What do you mean? There is no global variable.

Comment: I would like to have `ident var` as a class member or as a local variable in a method - instead of `::ident var`.

Comment: And what's stopping you? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Update the question and try to make it clear.

Comment: The question doesn't begin to make sense. You are trying to assign the value `0` to the definition of a class. This is not legal C++. You don't have any information about who downvoted your question, but FYI I was one of them, and I am certainly not a moderator here. And since your edit there is no now 'global variable in `Derived::method()`', or indeed any `Derived::method()` at all. Don't blame other people for the manifest shortcomings and self-contradictions in your own question.

Comment: I am still absolutely convinced that the real problem is the criminal affair

Comment: _"The question was very clear"_ - How can you say that when you asked for _"Is it possible to make it so `ident` refers to the global **variable** in `Derived::method()`?"_ but then you didn't have a global variable but a _type_ called `ident`? The fact that you accepted an answer where `ident` _is_ a variable while there is an answer that refers to `ident` as a _type_ makes it even more mysterious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the base depend on a template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
class DerivedLow : public T
{
    void method()
    {
        ident = 0; // Refers to the global entity.
    }
};

using Derived = DerivedLow<Base>;
```

Then nothing from the base class will be accessible in the derived class by default. You can still access base members with `this->` or `Base::`, or by importing them with `using`.

Comment: @mmomtchev If this answer is correct how exactly does `ident = 0` make sense when `ident` is a class?

Comment: @user207421 The question was edited 9 seconds before I posted this. Originally the global `ident` was a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You might add alias to hide base member:

```
class Derived : public Base {
  using ident = ::ident;
  ::ident var1; // OK, as before
  ident var2;   // OK, refer to typename Derived::ident (and so ::ident)
};
```